# PushPlugin Not Found Cordova 3.5

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, app-config, phonegap-pushplugin

I am following [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) tutorial to implement Push Notifications into my PhoneGap application. However I keep getting the following error in XCode:

```
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] CDVPlugin class PushPlugin (pluginName: PushPlugin) does not exist.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.427 Clubbed In[336:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"PushPlugin1224815266",
"PushPlugin",
"register",
[
 {
  "alert" : "true",
  "ecb" : "onNotificationAPN",
  "sound" : "true",
  "badge" : "true"
 }
]
```

I have put the 4 delegate/plugin files into my project's plugin folder successfully. In addition, I have added the PushNotification.js and referenced it correctly. I also have the following feature tags in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error? I am pretty sure that I correctly manually installed this PushPlugin.

Any help would truly be appreciated. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time...

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem with iOS 8. I looked at the code and it was in the layout in the answer below.

Comment: @tl8 I am in the same boat.  Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @Mike_G Sort of. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26111108/3562799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue. You need to change your plugin method signatures to match the new interface of CVDPlugin.h. e.g.

- (void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins