# Cordova Push Plugin iOS 8

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, ios8

Likely the same problem as [PhoneGap Push Plugin Does Not Register iOS 8 Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087429/phonegap-push-plugin-does-not-register-ios-8-device) but I do have an error message.

I have checked the plugin version and I am getting the new version with the iOS mods.

```
2014-09-26 15:50:54.070 Score My Selfies[401:89341] CDVPlugin class PushPlugin (pluginName: PushPlugin) does not exist.
2014-09-26 15:50:54.071 Score My Selfies[401:89341] ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-09-26 15:50:54.072 Score My Selfies[401:89341] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "PushPlugin599142626",
  "PushPlugin",
  "register",
  [
    {
      "alert" : "true",
      "ecb" : "onNotificationAPN",
      "sound" : "true",
      "badge" : "true" 
    }
  ]
```

I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding PushPlugin.m to the Build Phases->Compile Sources.

Not sure if this was a Cordova issue or a Netbeans issue.

Comment: Worked for me, I'm using PHP Storm

Comment: +1 for giving the answer to my question!

Registering for push did not work, even after updating the phonegap plugin to the most recent version.

After adding the file **PushPlugin.m** to **Build Phases->Compile Sources** it worked again!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the pull requests on github.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pulls

There are lots of iOS8 Fixes included. It doesn't look like they are merged into the phonegap-build repository yet.

iOS8 changed the way they register and handle push notifications so there are some code changes you will need to update to support iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, but I knew it had been working before. I already had trouble with plugins, so I am used to remove / re-add them... but it didn't work this time.

Using *git* I noticed that the `platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file is not correctly updated when I run the (sadly) usual :

`cordova plugin {remove,add} com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin`

Parts are missing in *PBXBuildFile* section ! **I guess it's a bug in cordova**...

### The solution

I worked it around by removing and re-adding the entire ios platform : 

`cordova platform {remove,add} ios`

This should do the trick.